# How to find all collection of numbers whose addition is same to the max number from list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

How to find all collection of numbers whose addition is same to the max number from list.
For Example:
Input array={2,3,4,9}
Output = {2,3,4}{9}

Comment: Can you start with what have you tried and where you are stuck? This question is most likely to get closed.

Comment: I think this is an algorithm type question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is actually the [SubsetSum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem.First find out the maximum value of the list and then apply Dynamic Programming to produce the set of numbers whose sum is maximum value of the list.

To implement *Dynamic Programming* for your problem in Java use recursion and HashTable. HashTable improves the performance by storing the computations.